# Pass multiple values(coming from lookup activity) in an argument to call stored procedure in script activity

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have output of Lookup activity as list of customer names.I have procedure that accepts argument as Customername String in Snowflake.I want to call the snowflake procedure from adf using script activity and pass the value from output of lookup.How can in achieve this for n number of customers.No need to iterate since there's only 1 record as list of customers.
[image]

I tried passing the value as : call procedure(?,?);
Parameter as : CustomerName

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the output you are getting in lookup activity.

```
 { "firstRow": 
     { "Customername": "Jaya" }, 
     "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (East US)", 
     "billingReference": { "activityType": "PipelineActivity", 
     "billableDuration": [ { "meterType": "AzureIR", "duration": 0.016666666666666666, "unit": "DIUHours" } ] }, 
     "durationInQueue": { "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0 } 
     }
```

Here there is only one Customername which can be accessed by pipeline activity variable as below.

```
@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Customername}
```

After connecting to snowflake, in query field use this as parameter while calling procedure as below.

```
CALL procedure(@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Customername});
```

Or add
`@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Customername}`

in parameter and `?`  as placeholder in procedure call.

If you are having different lookup activity as you said it is list, then below is the variable.

```
@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Customername[0]}
```

If you share Lookup activity output, it would be better for giving solution.